Error 1004 when trying to fill 2d array by using nested loop to run through cells
trying to fill a 2d array by using nested For loops to run through an area of cells starting at row 2 and going from A2 to E2, then A3 to E3, etc. The line that is erroring is below, starting "ArrayNew". The array itself is fine - worked ok as long as I was just filling one dimension from column 1. Any advice on what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!
(a and b have been declared as Long)
LRow=Sheets("MasterfileNew").Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
ReDim ArrayNew(1 to LRow, 1 to 5)
For a = 2 to LRow
For b = 1 to 5
ArrayNew(a-1,b)=Sheets("MasterfileNew").Range(Cells(a,b),Cells(a,b)).value '** erroring here**
Next b
Next a
I built in a Msgbox to return values, since this had worked originally for filling ArrayNew with values from first column only. The code throws an error 1004 at the line starting "ArrayNew(a-1,b)"
